# Reversing order in incrementing digits

Tags: python, list, numpy, sorting

I have a list of numbers, and I'm trying to do the following in a way as efficient as possible.

For each consecutively incrementing chunk in the list I have to reverse its order.

This is my attempt so far:

```
l = []
l_ = []
i = 0
while i <= len(a)-1:
    if a[i] < a[i+1]:
        l_= l_ + [a[i]]
    else:
        l = l_ + [a[i]]
        l_ = []
    i = i + 1
```

I'd appreciate any guidance or other approaches.

So, for the following list:

```
a = [1,5,7,3,2,5,4,45,1,5,10,12]
```

I would like to obtain:

```
[7,5,1,3,5,2,45,4,12,10,5,1]
```

Comment: how does your solution look like?

Comment: Please include the **quite long solution consisting in for loops** as it is helpful to those of us who may try to solve your problem. It is not currently clear how your numbers are chunked, as the numbers in the middle do not appear to have any definitive order.

Comment: Okay I'll include my current solution. sorry I'm quite new to SO

Comment: No worries, I don't want to sound harsh in my previous comment. It is always just best practices to include 1) code you have tried, 2) any input data (in your case the list is enough), 3) expected output (which you have included). All you are missing to make this a good question for SO is the code you have used.

Comment: Included my attempt so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

(with fixes from @Scott Boston and @myrmica)

```
nums = [1, 3, 5, 4, 6, 8, 9, 7, 2, 4] # sample input
chunk = []    # keep track of chunks
output = []   # output list
for i in nums:
    if chunk and i < chunk[-1]:
        output.extend(chunk[::-1]) # add reversed chunk to output
        chunk[:] = [i]       # clear chunk
    else:
        chunk.append(i)      # add to chunk
output.extend(chunk[::-1])   # empty leftover chunk
print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

with comprehension lists :

```
a = [1,5,7,3,2,5,4,45,1,5,10,12]

split=[0]+[i for i in range(1,len(a)) if a[i-1]>a[i]]+[len(a)]
#[0, 3, 4, 6, 8, 12]

chunks=[list(reversed(a[i:j])) for i,j in zip(split[:-1],split[1:])]
#[[7, 5, 1], [3], [5, 2], [45, 4], [12, 10, 5, 1]]

print(sum(chunks,[]))   
#[7, 5, 1, 3, 5, 2, 45, 4, 12, 10, 5, 1]
```